# One button "steals" another button's block?

Tags: android, button

If I press button 3 in my app, he first does HIS "tasks", then he does, what button 4 should do. Button 4 does nothing. Can you locate the error in my code?

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
    if(v == button1) 
    {MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.1);
     mediaPlayer.start();}
    if(v == button2)
    {MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.2);
     mediaPlayer.start();}  
    if(v == button3) 
    {MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.3);
     mediaPlayer.start();}
    if(v == button4)
    {MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.4);
     mediaPlayer.start();   
    }


    }
    return false;
}}
```

( the ACTION_DOWN is "grabbing" around that whole method, that is fine )

In another app I made, this structure works.

UPDATE:
I added functions for buttons 5 6 7 8 9 as well. Button 3 now executes EVERYTHING from 3 to 9.

Did I miss a bracket or sth like that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, I made an error in the assignment of the buttons.